# Netezza stored procedure returns error when creating external table that does not exists. I want it to return an empty table

Tags: sql, exception, netezza, stored-functions

I have a folder with csv files that have different dates in the name, which I have to import to Netezza. I have written 2 procedures: the first one has a loop which creates monthly dates within input parametes and the second procedure imports an individual file.
Everything works as long as the user inserts the dates for which the files exist.
For example I have files for 2011 (201101, 201102,...201112). If I use the dates between 01. 01. 2011 - 31. 12. 2011 the process will go through.
However if I use the dates between  01. 01. 2010 - 31. 12. 2012 I will get an error and no files imported.
In that case I would like to get the files for 2011 and maybe a message that the files for other dates do not exist.
Does any of you have a solution?
Here is the "second" procedure, where I create an external table:

```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NAME(NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(200),
> DATE, NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(200), CHARACTER VARYING(200),
> NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(2), NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(10),
> NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(20)) RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY) EXECUTE
> AS CALLER LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS BEGIN_PROC
> 
>  DECLARE    vAM_REC ALIAS FOR $1;   vDATE ALIAS FOR $2;   vDELOKNJ
> ALIAS FOR $3; -- location of the file  vFILENAME ALIAS FOR $4; -- name
> of the file  vPREFIX ALIAS FOR $5;   vVERSION ALIAS FOR $6;   vDB
> ALIAS FOR $7;     vSQL NVARCHAR;   vDRP NVARCHAR; 
> 
> BEGIN
> 
> vDRP := 'DROP TABLE '||vDB||'..TABLE_NAME IF EXISTS';  EXECUTE
> IMMEDIATE vDRP;    vSQL := 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
> '||vDB||'..TABLE_NAME ( COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3      )   USING (      
> DATAOBJECT('''||vDELOKNJ||''||vFILENAME||''')       REMOTESOURCE
> ''ODBC''    DELIMITER '',''     MAXERRORS 1     QUOTEDVALUE ''DOUBLE''    
> LOGDIR ''C:\TEMP''      SKIPROWS 1      )'      ; 
>      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL; 
> 
> 
>       vSQL := 'INSERT INTO
> '||vDB||'..'||vPREFIX||'_TABLE_NAME_'||vVERSION||'            SELECT
>               *           FROM
>               TABLE_NAME          ';      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;
> 
> 
> DROP TABLE TMP_IFRS17_RAFM_OUTPUT_INDIVIDUAL IF EXISTS;
> 
> RETURN 'Procedure Completed';
> --
> --'EXCEPTION
> --WHEN OTHERS THEN'
> --RAISE NOTICE 'Error in Procedure Execution  --- > %',SQLERRM;
> --
> --RETURN 'FAILURE'; 
END; END_PROC;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't you move the exception handling to the statement that is producing the error?

Comment: What do you mean by that?
If I am not mistaken the statement that is producing an error is "INSERT INTO".
How do I do that?
I have been unsuccessful with all my efforts with "exception handling" :/.

Comment: Sorry as I'm not too familiar with this tech. But I'd say either (or both) EXACTLY after the second `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL` or the third one